# Scala: Elegant conversion of a string into a boolean

Tags: scala

In Java you can write `Boolean.valueOf(myString)`. However in Scala, `java.lang.Boolean` is hidden by `scala.Boolean` which lacks this function. It's easy enough to switch to using the original Java version of a boolean, but that just doesn't seem right.

So what is the one-line, canonical solution in Scala for extracting `true` from a string?

Comment: Why not simply use a regular expression?

Comment: It doesn't sound simple at all.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Ah, I am silly. The answer is `myString.toBoolean`.

Comment: If myString is null your code will throw an Exception, I prefer the next answer approach Try(myString.toBoolean).getOrElse(false)

Comment: `Try(myString.toBoolean).getOrElse(false)` will go through the work of throwing and catching the exception. `Option(myString).exists(_.toBoolean)` avoids that extra effort.

Comment: Using `Try(myString.toBoolean).getOrElse(false)` is good. Handles non-matching string cleanly.

Answer (score 115):

How about this:

```
import scala.util.Try

Try(myString.toBoolean).getOrElse(false)
```

If the input string does not convert to a valid Boolean value `false` is returned as opposed to throwing an exception.  This behavior more closely resembles the Java behavior of [`Boolean.valueOf(myString)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

Comment: I think an exception is what you want. What if the user enters "1" instead of "true" or something else? This approach will leave such an error undetected. But now I know about the Try function, which is nice.

Answer (score 28):

`Scala 2.13` introduced [`String::toBooleanOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toBooleanOption:Option[Boolean]), which combined to [`Option::getOrElse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#getOrElse[B%3E:A](default:=%3EB):B), provides a safe way to extract a `Boolean` as a `String`:

```
"true".toBooleanOption.getOrElse(false)  // true
"false".toBooleanOption.getOrElse(false) // false
"oups".toBooleanOption.getOrElse(false)  // false
```

Answer (score 11):

Note: Don't write `new Boolean(myString)` in Java - always use `Boolean.valueOf(myString)`. Using the `new` variant unnecessarily creates a `Boolean` object; using the `valueOf` variant doesn't do this.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with `myString.toBoolean` is that it will throw an exception if `myString.toLowerCase` isn't exactly one of `"true"` or `"false"` (even extra white space in the string will cause an exception to be thrown).

If you want exactly the same behaviour as `java.lang.Boolean.valueOf`, then use it fully qualified, or import Boolean under a different name, eg, `import java.lang.{Boolean=>JBoolean}; JBoolean.valueOf(myString)`. Or write your own method that handles your own particular circumstances (eg, you may want `"t"` to be `true` as well).

Comment: This is not true (anymore). `toLowerCase is done by `toBoolean`

Answer (score 2):

I've been having fun with this today, mapping a 1/0 set of values to boolean. I had to revert back to Spark 1.4.1, and I finally got it working with:

```
Try(if (p(11).toString == "1" || p(11).toString == "true") true else false).getOrElse(false))
```

where p(11) is the dataframe field

my previous version didn't have the "Try", this works, other ways of doing it are available ...

Comment: You don't need the `if` with the `true else false` because your conditional returns `true` or `false`.  All you need is `Try(condition).getOrElse(false)`.