# How can I access a form from value in a Play Framework 2 template?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am only able to access a form value in my Play Framework 2 template like this:

```
@eventForm("options[0].safeToDelete").value.toString()
```

But I need to also be able to access it from within a method in the template, like this:

```
optionFields(option: Field)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang) = {
    @option("safeToDelete").value.toString()
}
@optionFields(eventForm("options[0]"))
```

The first example returns `true`.

The second one returns `Some(true)`.

How can I get the second one to return `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala `Option[T]` is a different way of handling null objects.

It has two subtypes - `Some[T]` and `None`. One of the many ways you can handle this is as below,

```
@option("safeToDelete").value.getOrElse(false).toString
```

Read through for more.. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_options.htm

Comment: This got my value, but it doesn't seem to work in a conditional.  I tried `@if(option("safeToDelete").value.getOrElse(false)){...}` but got `type mismatch; found : Any required: Boolean Note: implicit method implicitFieldConstructor is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type`

Comment: Can you try `option("safeToDelete").value.getOrElse(false).asInstanceOf[Boolean]`

Comment: That causes this exception: `ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`

Comment: Ok. This is pure guesswork, I have no way of trying this out at the moment, but I would try `option("safeToDelete").value.getOrElse("false").toBoolean`. Note that the value `"false"` appears in quotes. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470230/scala-elegant-conversion-of-a-string-into-a-boolean

Comment: This ended up working, although it doesn't seem that elegant:  `@if(option("safeToDelete").value.getOrElse("false").toString() == "true"){...}`