# How to extract boolean values from XML to Scala case class

Tags: scala, xml-parsing, playframework-2.0

I've just started with Scala, so please bear with my newbie question. :) I'm exploring the wonderful powers of XML support in Scala, and came to a task: I have an XML document with a node containing a boolean-like value: `<bool_node>true</bool_node>`. I also have a case class with a boolean field in it. What I want to achieve is to create an instance of that class from the XML.

The problem, obviously, is that for XML `<bool_node>` contains just a string, not boolean. What is the best way to handle this situation? Just try to convert that string to boolean using `myString.toBoolean`? Or some other approach could is better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470230/scala-elegant-conversion-of-a-string-into-a-boolean

Comment: @alexwriteshere thanks, I've seen that question, and I'm aware about `toBoolean` method. Just wandering if XML needs some special treatment, or there are some best practices, like validation.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like using pattern matching for XML.

The simplest approach would be something like:

```
// This would have come from somewhere else
val sourceData = <root><bool_node>true</bool_node></root>

// Notice the XML on the left hand side. This is because the left hand side is a
// pattern, for pattern matching.
// This will set stringBool to "true"
val <root><bool_node>{stringBool}</bool_node><root> = sourceData

// stringBool is a String, so must be converted to a Boolean before use
val myBool = stringBool.toBoolean
```

Another approach, which might make sense if this happens a lot, is to define your own extractor:

```
// This only has to be defined once
import scala.xml.{NodeSeq, Text}
object Bool {
  def unapply(node: NodeSeq) = node match {
    case Text("true") => Some(true)
    case Text("false") => Some(false)
    case _ => None
  }
}

// Again, notice the XML on the left hand side. This will set myBool to true.
// myBool is already a Boolean, so no further conversion is necessary
val <root><bool_node>{Bool(myBool)}</bool_node></root> = sourceData
```

Or, if you're using the XPath sytle syntax, this will work:

```
val myBool = (xml \ "bool_node").text.toBoolean
```

Or, you can mix and match them as you see fit - both the pattern matching and XPath syntaxes are composable and interoperable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's informative. I'm not accepting it because StackOverflow questions with accepted answers tend to be ignored by community, and I'm still hoping somebody will provide some more info, or maybe another examples, or at least give this answer +1, to indicate that it's complete and nothing could be added.