# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: " false"

Tags: scala

```
enter code here
package anotherExample

object StringSplitter {
  def computePercentTrue(line: String): Double = {
    val splits: Array[String] = line.split(";")
    var totalCount: Double = 0
    //println("Hi!")
    var trueCount: Double = 0
    for (value <- splits) {
      //println("Hello!")
      val valueAsBoolean: Boolean = value.toBoolean
      //println(3)
      if (valueAsBoolean) {
        trueCount += 1
      }
      totalCount += 1
    }
    trueCount / totalCount
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val testInput = "true; false; true; true; true"
    val percentTrue = computePercentTrue(testInput) // expecting 0.8
    println("Percentage true == " + percentTrue)
  }


}
```

Hi, so the point of this code is given a string of boolean values(true/false) and splitting by semicolons, I'm trying to return the percentage of values that are true. I don't understand the error message and I'm new to Scala, so can someone explain what's going on? I'm getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: " false"
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.parseBoolean(StringLike.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toBoolean(StringLike.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toBoolean$(StringLike.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toBoolean(StringOps.scala:33)
    at anotherExample.StringSplitter$.$anonfun$computePercentTrue$1(StringSplitter.scala:11)
    at anotherExample.StringSplitter$.$anonfun$computePercentTrue$1$adapted(StringSplitter.scala:9)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at anotherExample.StringSplitter$.computePercentTrue(StringSplitter.scala:9)
    at anotherExample.StringSplitter$.main(StringSplitter.scala:23)
    at anotherExample.StringSplitter.main(StringSplitter.scala)
```

Comment: “ false” contains a leading space.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize spaces mattered when you're using .split

Comment: Spaces matter when converting to a boolean value using toBoolean, hence the format parse error (note the helpful stacktrace and specific value in the message). Split does not care and does exactly as it was told. Consider a *minimal* SSCCE: “ false”.toBoolean

Comment: Once identifying that issue the Y question might be: “How to split on a character and eliminate surrounding white space?”

Comment: you can use trim  `val valueAsBoolean: Boolean = value.trim.toBoolean`

Answer (score 2):

As *@asanand* mentioned in his comment, you should use trim.

In ***Scala 2.13*** you can do it entirely safe (no `Exception`), use this:

```
stringValue.trim.toBooleanOption.getOrElse(false)
```

Or with previous Versions:

```
Try(stringValue.trim.toBoolean).getOrElse(false)
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991592/2750966

By the way in ***Scala*** always try to avoid mutable state `var`s.

Here an example using `foldLeft`:

```
def computePercentTrue(line: String): Double = {
   val (trueCount, totalCount) = 
      line.split(";")
        .foldLeft((0.0, 0)){case ((count, total), value) => 
           (if(value.trim.toBooleanOption.getOrElse(false))
               count + 1
            else 
               count
            , total + 1)
        } 
   trueCount / totalCount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regex solution you can be a bit more forgiving of poorly formatted input.

```
def computePercentTrue(line: String): Double = {
  val vctr = "(true|false)".r.findAllMatchIn(line)
                           .map(_.group(1)=="true")
                           .toVector
  vctr.count(identity) / vctr.length.toDouble
}

computePercentTrue("true;; false;x; true=true -- true")
//res0: Double = 0.8
```